# ReactJS - Edge browser throws append error in setState

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-edge

I'm using ReactJS and have a grid I'm populating with data. I've abstracted the grid so that all we need to do is pass props for columns and data (columnDefinitions - an array of column info, gridData - object). The problem I'm having is when populating the state of the component I do something like this:

```
this.state = {
      gridOptions: {
        colDefs: columnDefinitions,
        ...
      }
    }
```

Then in the componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount(){
this.setState( { rowData: this.props.gridData });
```

}

This works fine in Chrome but in Edge (v41) I get Object doesn't support property or method 'append'.

If I changed define the colDef: [] array manually instead of a passed in prop no problem but then I can't abstract.

Answer (score 0):

`.append` is not universally accepted.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

Are you using a transpiler like babel? The link also has a polyfill for `.append`

```
(function (arr) {
  arr.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('append')) {
      return;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(item, 'append', {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: function append() {
        var argArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
          docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

        argArr.forEach(function (argItem) {
          var isNode = argItem instanceof Node;
          docFrag.appendChild(isNode ? argItem : document.createTextNode(String(argItem)));
        });

        this.appendChild(docFrag);
      }
    });
  });
})([Element.prototype, Document.prototype, DocumentFragment.prototype]);
```

Comment: we are using babel.

Comment: @user1015196 Does the polyfill not work? You didn't comment on it

Comment: sorry forgot a little scattered today. No it does not work. I'm new to ReactJS world so just make sure I'm doing this right I just added the following to my index.js file: import "babel-polyfill";

Comment: @user1015196 Where did copy/paste this polyfill function I have posted in this answer? Try having it in the file that has `ReactDOM.render` and placing it above `ReactDOM.render`. Usually the file is called `index.js`

Comment: yes that where I put it in the index.js well in our case it is index.jsx